# How do the dependencies of a maven project become available to it at runtime?

Tags: maven, dependencies, communication

I have my POJOs and DAOs in one maven project (Project A)
And I have created a Service in another maven project collecting the DAOs I need (in Project B)
And I created a third maven Project with a swing gui main class(Project C)

Project C depends on B and B depends on A.

When I declare my service(Project B) to use the functions to fetch data to the gui (Project C) I get a Java Null Pointer Exception on the Resource use of my service.

Cant the project communicate just trough dependencies or do I need some deserialization etc.?

LOGIC
POJO(implements Serializable) -> DAO -> Service -> GUI

Comment: it's not a bad question really, just confusing

Comment: you need to read about the dependency mechanism of maven too.  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Can it be so simple that i have to add applicationContext from Project A or B -> C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what i needed to fetch data from my maven project (Project A) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/LoadconfigwithFileSystemXmlApplicationContext.htm

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that you are executing the code in Project C.  It would help to know what the types of these projects are . . . but let's just assume they are jars.  By default, a jar is NOT built to include all of it's dependencies inside of itself.  This is because Maven expects you to use jars like most people in the java community do, i.e. they are installed into runtimes along with all of the other jars needed.  If each jar had it's fully dependency tree included inside of itself, that would be a mess.  So, it seems that you are expecting the Maven build to pull all of your dependency chain into your final artifact for Project C, and it's not happening.

There are several ways to get your dependencies into your final artifact.  Assuming your swing project is a jar, you could do this with the assembly plugin's "jar-with-dependencies" assembly type.  It produces a jar with all of it's dependencies included.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

Comment: They are jars and theres only a main function running in Project C

Comment: I do not have any problem with adding the dependency, the classes and methods from Project A and B are available to Project C after Project C has them as a dependency. But when the methods from project B are used in Project C they throw a nullpointer exception

Comment: I see . . . it sounds like it has to do with the code, not the build.  If the classes are available at run time, you don't really have a build issue.

Comment: Probably not the build, What i am trying to do is Access my DAOs that exists in a maven project from a new JavaFX project(GUI). I have added the maven project jar in the FX project library. But when i import the DAO classes and use a function (for example findAll()) the call to the mavenproject returns Null Pointer Exception